Show that no prime number less than 600 divides any number $2^{2^n}+1$, no matter how large n is.
I came across this while reading Euler's E054. All that is said is that this statement (in the title) "can still be easily proved". I know $641\mid2^{2^5}+1$, but why and how 600 is produced I do not. I do not know even where to begin.

$p=5$ divides $n=1.$ Is there something missing from your statement?

If it means no $2^{2^n}+1$ which is not prime is divisible by a prime $<600,$ I bet this can be proved on a case-by-case basis. If $2^{2^n}+1$ is divisible by $p,$ then $p\equiv1\pmod{2^n}.$ Since when $n =1,2,3,4$ it is known that $2^{2^n}+1$ is prime, we can restrict to $n\geq 5$ or $p\equiv1\pmod{32}.$ That reduces the number of primes you need to check considerably: $17,97,161,...$

Here are the factorisations for $n<9$ https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJwdyDEKgDAMQNG9p%5FhbU%2DxiNwtepRDESpZWovdH8I2vT8ewweM6rlO2VAOAslOalGaJhfW%5F2228YplYY6br8U4XTSl8hNER1g==&lang=sage
